# how to make field non searchable in spring-data-jpa-solr

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

I am using `solr-spring-data` `JPA` for query and saving in `solr`.
I added

```
@SolrDocument(collection = "test")
```

on POJO and on field level

i added

```
(name= "field1", searchable=false),
```

but still i am able to query from field1, so how to make field `nonseachble` in `spring-data-jpa` for `solr`.

Comment: Use Indexed. "@Indexed" has to be added with readonly=true to ignore fields from being written to Solr. "@Indexed(readonly = true)"

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.1.0.M2/reference/html/#reference

Comment: i want to write field in solr,but not want to search on this field

Comment: Have you added like "@Indexed(name = "field1", type = "string", searchable = false)"

Comment: yes i added , then i try to search from field1, it still giving me result

Comment: after modifying the same..didi you reindex the data..?

Comment: yes , i created the new core(collection) for it.